# Map HttpPost data to model in MVC - How to capture data with "-" in name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, iis, http-post

If I have a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ReturnType ControllerMethod(CustomModel c)
{
...
}
```

A third party is posting data to this method:

```
abc-xyz=testdata
```

One way, would be to use:

```
Request.Params["abc-xyz"]
```

However, in the case where the Request could contain malicious code, if any Request Parameter contained some problematic code, IIS would throw an `HttpRequestValidationException` as soon as `Request.Params[""]` is called.

Now, rather than turn off that validation everywhere, I'd like to map the posted data to my model. That way, if the "potentially malicious code" is contained in any parameter that isn't "abc-xyz", my application won't throw a `HttpRequestValidationException`. It will however, check the used paramaters, and throw a `HttpRequestValidationException` if the *accessed* data is potentially malicious.

How do I do that if the posted data has a dash/hyphen in the name?

I've tried a few variations including:

```
public class CustomModel
{
    [Required]
    public string abc_xyz
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your own `ModelBinder` in this case that transforms the values from the request into the ones needed for `CustomModel`.

To over come the request validation, you can turn it off with the `ValidateInputAttribute` on your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've found a few articles discussing writing custom ModelBinder. However, they all seem like fairly chunky pieces of code which complicate my codebase. I guess I expected a simple annotation to do the job Ie: [Mapping("abc-xyz")].

Comment: there isn't one of the box. that is the responsibility model binder.

Comment: OK, thanks. I did put together a custom model binder, but when I try to access the Request parameters, it still throws a HttpRequestValidationException. The in-built ModelBinder does not throw this exception.